# JsonArrayをReturnさせたいです。

Tags: c#, json

Visual Studio2013のc#でAPIを開発しています。

DBから引き出したデータをJsonArrayにしてReturnさせたいと思います。
コード作成してFiddlerで試してみましたが、
このように結果がでました。これってJsonArrayがちゃんとReturnされているのでしょうか？
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

次は自分のソースコードです。

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray jsontest = new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray();

for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++ )
{
    Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject json = new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject();
    json.Add("name", "kim " + i);
    json.Add("age", "20 " + i);
    json.Add("job", "programer " + i);

    jsontest.Add(json);
}

return Json(jsontest);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSONとして正しいレスポンスを出力できているか、ということでしょうか？

Fiddlerでそのように表示されるのであれば、（Fiddlerが認識できる）正しいJSONと言えるかと思います。